# Avoid Calling a function repeateadly unless its job is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that needs to be called after 5 seconds time interval. This function processes AJAX request in the background (the request goes to other website, so it may take a few seconds). The function is as follows:

```
function myFunction() {
    var sendData = {
        cid: cid
    };
    $.post('xyz.com/somepage.php', sendData, function(response) {
        //processes the response
    });
    setTimeout(myFunction, 5000); //call again after 5 seconds
}
```

I need to consider a fact that some users may have slow internet connection and the request can take time more than 5 seconds. So, I need to avoid calling that function (or we say avoid sending request) again until its job is finished. I tried the method given in the last paragraph on this [link](https://sarfraznawaz.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/javascript-self-invoking-functions/), but it didn't work. Any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest that you look at `promises` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call the function on completion of ajax call

```
function myFunction() {
    var sendData = {
        cid: cid
    };
    $.post('xyz.com/somepage.php', sendData, function(response) {
        //processes the response
    }).done(function() {
        setTimeout(myFunction, 5000); //call again after 5 seconds
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Place the `setTimeout` call within the callback handler:

```
function myFunction() {
    $.post('xyz.com/somepage.php', { cid: cid }, function(response){
        //processes the response

        setTimeout(myFunction, 5000);//call again after 5 seconds
    });
}
```